run google cmdline-tools in Android phone
I worked on the ADB shell in recent days for a project.
in this project I need to make an app or device to control another android phone with ADB shell command with wifi debbuging or usb debbuging. like i call "open an app" or "close a app" or maybe "get an app package name".
I don't have problem doing this on a pc, cuse using cmd line tools is simple.
my problem is I want to make a hand-held device to control that other android devices.
i think it's hard to make this project with a esp-32 or a Arduino (cause I want to close-source it)
so for now I want to make an android application to simply runs on an Android device.
but I do not know how to do it.
but I'm thinking of an app that we simply make a button in it to run a command like "ADB connect (ip-adress)" when button is pressed.
the only want to run adb shell commands like:
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName

or
adb shell pm list packages

i also want to hear your ideas for doing this project it th.

Android and it's tools are open source so you have the whole adb source code and thus can see the protocol. Or you use an USB sniffer program on the PC to see what is transmitted via USB. Last bug not least there is Termux which I think provides precomoiked adb packages, but I am not sure how useful they are in a separate app.

@Robert thanks for your reply. I must say, I have never worked on "editing an open-source tool" and I don't know where to start learning it. I will also be very thankful if you mention an article or web page to learn that. it also includes termux cause I think its open source.
